# C# db sample code throws "Connection property has not been initialized"

Tags: c#, sql-server, exception, connection

I've installed sql server db on my machine, and visual studio "server explorer" can connect to it, and the connection string is provided in "property", I then use this string to write my C# code as below:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(
    "Data Source=MININT-EP12N1V;Initial Catalog=EmployeeDB;Integrated Security=True");
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select FirstName, LastName from Employees");
//above sql can be executed in sql server management studio successfully.
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();//throws exception
while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.Write("{1}, {0}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1));
}
reader.Close();
cmd.Dispose();
conn.Close();
```

It throws out exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
```

So how to fix it?

Comment: by setting SqlCommand's Connection property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the `SqlConnection` to the `SqlCommand` which is required as command does not know that on which server it needs to execute the query unless you provide the connection details.

Try :

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select FirstName, LastName from Employees",conn);
```

You can always see the [examples provided in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader).

You can see in the docs example the approach to do. you should wrap connection in using so that it gets disposed off as soon as the code block exits :

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(
    "Data Source=MININT-EP12N1V;Initial Catalog=EmployeeDB;Integrated Security=True"))
{

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select FirstName, LastName from Employees");
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    conn.Open();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.Write("{1}, {0}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1));
    }
    reader.Close();
    cmd.Dispose();
}
```